# checksum a pipeline

Tags: pipe, filter, checksum

I want to construct a huge blob of data (a backup of a sort) and send it over the network (ssh or rsync) to another host. There is enough space on the remote for the data, but not on the local host, so I cannot store it as a local file. I'd like to compute a checksum of the data as it is entering the pipe (and later compare with the checksum of the resulting remote file). So I'm looking for a program that I can put in the middle of a pipeline and let it compute a checksum of everything passing through.

Two "MITM" programs that pop up in my head are `pv` and `mbuffer` but neither seems to have this functionality. Also `cat` and `dd` fall short :-) The various programs for computing checksums like `md5sum`, `sha1sum` etc. all consume their input and do not pass it on. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tee` and process substitution `>(…)`, e.g.

```
cat blob | tee >(md5sum >&2) | ssh user@remote 'tee >(md5sum >&2) >/tmp/blob'
```

This pipe is writing the checksums to stderr to not interfere with stdout.
You can redirect the hash to a file if you want to keep it.

```
cat blob | tee >(md5sum >blob.md5) | <your pipe>
```

Comment: So first, this is dependent on the shell being bash or ksh (it isn't either, but I could install bash easily). But more importantly, isn't this implemented with a temporary file?

Comment: Sorry, yes. It depends on the shell. It's implemented with pipes using named file 
descriptors (`/dev/fd/n`) where available or named FIFOs. No temporary files involved.